# undefined method `user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to construct a users model manually (without using 'resources :users' in the routes.rb file). My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show'
match '/all_users', :to => 'users#index'
```

This is my index method in the users controller:

```
def index
  @title = "All users"
  @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

This is my index view:

```
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.email, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

I get this error message when I hit localhost:3000/all_users:

```
undefined method `user_path'
```

I don't see where this is coming from.

EDIT:

Ok, I've discovered that changing 'user' to '@user' in the view makes it work:

```
<%= link_to user.email, @user %>
```

But I really don't understand the error message, or the real difference between 'user' and '@user'. Plus, clicking on the link created does not redirect to the user's page, it stays on localhost:3000/all_users.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show'
```

should be

```
match '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user
```

The `:as` parameter tells the router what to name the route as (You can then add `_path` or `_url` to whatever the `:as` parameter is).

Also, any time you link directly to an ActiveRecord model (e.g. `link_to user.email, user`), it will try to turn `user` into `user_path`.

Comment: for anyone using rails 4 use this instead `get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user`

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who using rails 4 in your routes.rb `post '/users', :to => 'users#create', :as => :user` and you controller `render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user_path`